Identifying Dataweave functions/ modules based on Dataweave Class names in Heap Dump
I have an app which is failing with out of memory issue and created a hprof file during load. Heap Dump Histogram
I have tried to analyse the hprof using jhat and got below histogram view from it.
I could see that some dataweave related classes with big sizes on the top. I am willing to re-design or improve the code but not able to figure out what dataweave functions that are used in my code are linked to highlighted classes in the screenshot.
Could anyone please shed some light?
Heap Dump Histogram

That's not the best way to analyze a heap dump, and it is very unlikely that you will be able to associate objects in the heap to functions in the code this way. Functions are not objects, hence not obvious in a heap dump. Use a more capable tool like Eclipse MAT to analyze the heap dump and try to follow some tutorials on how to analyze a heap dump. It is a bit of an art. Also read [ask]. This question is missing a [mre] so we can understand the issue.

Also share the names of the classes as text. It is not possible to copy the names from an image to research them. I have a suspicion but I need more information to confirm before suggesting something.
